# Randomly changing CSS styles

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make the cell change color along with the Styles. I do not know what would be best. Either to put it in the CSS style sheet or just straight in the html. I am a bit confused on this if someone could help that would be great. Thanks to anyone who contributes.

HTML Code:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>HTML and JavaScript</title>
<link href="Capstone 10_2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
<script>
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }


  function stylize() 
  {
    var index = getRandomInt(1, 20);
    var s = "myStyle" + index;
    var e = document.getElementById("MessageText");
    e.className = s;
    setTimeout("stylize()", 1500);
    return;
  }

 </script>
 </head>

 <body onLoad="stylize()">
  <table align="center" border="1" bordercolor="black">
   <tr>
    <td align="center">
     <font size="3"><b>STYLE CLASS VIEWER</b></font>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td align="center" height="100" width="400">
     <div id="MessageText" class="myStyle1">
      Hello World Wide Web!
     <div>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>

</html>
```

CSS code:

```
.myStyle1 {font-family:Impact; color:black; font-size:10; backgroundcolor: black}
.myStyle2 {font-family:Georgia; color:black; font-size:18; backgroundcolor: black}
.myStyl31 {font-family:Tahoma; color:red; font-size:24; backgroundcolor: black}
.myStyle4 {font-family:Verdana; color:black; font-size:48; backgroundcolor: black}
.myStyle5 {font-family:Impact; color:red; font-size:30; backgroundcolor: black}
.myStyle6 {font-family:Marlett; color:green; font-size:35; backgroundcolor: black}
.myStyle7 {font-family:Arial; color:blue; font-size:40; backgroundcolor: black}
.myStyle8 {font-family:Courier Sans MS Bold; color:blue; font-size:30; backgroundcolor: black}
.myStyle9 {font-family:Impact; color:blue; font-size:35; backgroundcolor: black}
.myStyle10 {font-family:Arial Italic; color:blue; font-size:10; backgroundcolor: black}
.myStyle11 {font-family:Times New Roman; color:blue; font-size:50; backgroundcolor: black}
.myStyle12 {font-family:Tahoma; color:blue; font-size:38; backgroundcolor: black}
.myStyle13 {font-family:Verdana; color:green; font-size:30; backgroundcolor: black}
.myStyle14 {font-family:Marlett; color:blue; font-size:20; backgroundcolor: black}
.myStyle15 {font-family:Impact; color:blue; font-size:24; backgroundcolor: black}
.myStyle16 {font-family:Georgia; color:blue; font-size:24; backgroundcolor: black}
.myStyle17 {font-family:Impact; color:blue; font-size:35; backgroundcolor: black}
.myStyle18 {font-family:Georgia; color:red; font-size:12; backgroundcolor: black}
.myStyle19 {font-family:Arial; color:green; font-size:20; backgroundcolor: black}
.myStyle20 {font-family:Tahoma; color:blue; font-size:55; backgroundcolor: black}
```

I do not know whether to use this:

```
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('MessageText'),
    colors = ['000000','FF0000','00FF00','0000FF','FFFF00','00FFFF','FF00FF','C0C0C0'];

for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].style.backgroundColor = '#' + colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
}
```

Or maybe I am just way off on this code.

Comment: not clear what expected behavior is. You say *"make **the** cell change"* but show code for looping all cells

Comment: I want like the little cell to change colors when refreshed etc.

Comment: *"the little cell"* ????

Comment: The cell where the text changes from the CSS Styles

Comment: why can't you just change the class to that cell instead of the `<div>`?

Comment: What do you mean by that, I am extremely new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little demo using your HTML and CSS that allow the cell background color and text style to change randomly upon page load.

The CSS will remain the same. The only real addition I made to the HTML was adding an id on the TD element and closing a div tag properly.

HTML Code:

```
<body>
  <table align="center" border="1" bordercolor="black">
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <font size="3"><b>STYLE CLASS VIEWER</b></font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="MessageCell" align="center" height="100" width="400">
        <div id="MessageText" class="myStyle1">
          Hello World Wide Web!
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var messageCell = document.getElementById('MessageCell');
var messageText = document.getElementById('MessageText');

function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function setRandomColor() {
  messageCell.setAttribute("style","background-color: " + getRandomColor() + ";");
}

function setRandomClass() {
    var randomStyleNumber = getRandomInt(1, 20);
    messageText.setAttribute("class", 'myStyle' + randomStyleNumber);
}

function stylize() {
    setRandomClass();
    setRandomColor();
}

stylize();
```

Here's a JSFiddle example:

https://jsfiddle.net/4t6etg7c/1/

I hope this helps, have fun learning!

Comment: I would use this but I have to stay in the Stylize() class

Comment: Okay...changing it to use stylize() is trivial as you can see in the edit. Sounds like it must be a homework question...better hit them books bro.

Comment: Yea I have been its just he gave us work that we haven't learned yet and said go do this. I am trying to teach myself its just a hard process.

Comment: Anther quick question how would I get this to work in the <head></head>? Because I cannot seem a way to get it

Comment: If you're putting in <head>, wrap it in a <script> tag and wrap it in document.onLoad like this: document.onLoad = function() { /* code goes here */};

Comment: If you were able to make use of my answer it would be much appreciated if you could accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Set **all** CSS values with JavaScript.

```
el.style.fontSize = ...
el.style.color = ...
el.style.backgroundColor = ...
el.style.fontFamily = ...
```

There is **no** **need** to write multiple CSS classes anymore.

```js
function getRandColor() {
  var hex = "01234567890ABCDEF",
    res = "#";
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i += 1) {
    res += hex[Math.floor(Math.random() * hex.length)];
  }
  return res;
}

function getRandNumber(s, e) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (e - s + 1)) + s;
}

function getRandFontFamily() {
  var fontFamilies = ["Impact", "Georgia", "Tahoma", "Verdana", "Impact", "Marlet"]; // Add more
  return fontFamilies[Math.floor(Math.random() * fontFamilies.length)];
}

function stylize() {
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
      text.style.fontFamily = getRandFontFamily();
      text.style.color = getRandColor();
      text.style.fontSize = getRandNumber(15, 35) + "px"; // Font sizes between 15px and 35px
      text.style.backgroundColor = getRandColor();
    },
    1500);
}

stylize();
```

```html
<table align="center" border="1" bordercolor="black">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <font size="3"><b>STYLE CLASS VIEWER</b></font>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" height="100" width="400">
      <div id="text">
        Hello World Wide Web!
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Remark**

Run the JavaScript either at the end of `<body>`

```
<body>
...
<script>
...
</script>
</body>
```

**or** in `<head>` like

```
<head>
<script>
 ...
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
     stylize()
 });
</script>
</head>
```